Vue component with generic is typed 'unknown'
The following example triggers an ESLint error: 'unknown' overrides all other types in this union type. (@typescript-eslint/no-redundant-type-constituents).
// MyTest.vue

<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
import { Ref, ref } from "vue";

const t: Ref<T | null> = ref(null);
</script>

<template>Hello</template>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>

I don't understand: I have a generic type T (which is non-nullable in general) and I want a ref of type T | null. This seems like the correct way to do that.
On the other hand, the following example do not trigger an ESLint error (as expected).
// test.ts

function createRef<T>() {
  const myRef: Ref<T | null> = ref(null);
  return myRef;
};

So it seems that ESLint handles generics in Vue components differently than in a regular function... Is this intended? Am I missing something?

Every tool works in its own way when it comes to non-spec-compliant stuff like TS and especially Vue SFC. Unless you can consistently reproduce the problem with a range of different tools (IDE, linter, vue-tsc), you can consider it a bug of a specific tool and address it accordingly. Update to the latest versions, if this doesn't help, open an issue

I just encountered this bug, has an issue been filed on github?
